# What has been the traditional practice and advise to prevent dehydration during fasting?

Tags: hadith, sawm

As people of the desert, early muslims must have been very familiar with dehydration. Did prophet Muhammad (pbuh) or his successors and later religious leaders offer any advice on how to prevent dehydration during fasting? Are there any Hadiths recommending a particular diet during fasting to prevent dehydration? Documented historical and cultural practices that were observed during fasting but aren't necessarily a part of Islamic theology would also be helpful.